# Associate child object with parent object per instance in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've got two models, an `Invoice` model and an `Expense` model. Upon creating invoices, the user should be able to add all expenses for an invoice. Once an invoice has been created - these expenses should somehow be "checked" so a new invoice doesn't add the same expenses. I'd need some form of check on the expense instance saying "has been invoiced" or something. Not entirely sure how to proceed with only a `..set.filter(...)` queryset  My two models looks like this:

Expense model

```
class Expense(Model):
    cost = DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    project = ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE) 
    billable = BooleanField(default=False)
    expense_date = DateField()
    date_created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    invoice = ForeignKey("finances.Invoice", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=SET_NULL, help_text="Optionally link this to an existing invoice")
```

Invoice model

```
class Invoice(Model):
    issue_date = DateField(default=now)
    due_date = DateField()
    project = ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)
    amount = DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    include_expenses = BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Check this box to include all expenses that are within the invoice billable date range')
    billable_start = DateField(help_text="Logged hours start date")
    billable_end = DateField(help_text="Logged hours end date")
```

I tried adding a queryset on the Expense model as such:

```
    def get_billable_expenses(self):
        """Getting all expenses for selected billable period"""
        start_week = self.get_start_isoweek()
        end_week = self.get_end_isoweek()
        return self.project.expense_set.filter(
            expense_date__gte=self.billable_start, 
            expense_date__lte=self.billable_end,
            billable=True,
            invoice=self.id
        )
```

And then adding a signal that is triggered when an invoice is saved:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Invoice)
def prepare_calculation_data(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        expenses_to_add = []
        for expense in instance.get_billable_expenses():
            expense.invoice = instance
            expenses_to_add.append(expense)
        Expense.objects.bulk_update(expenses_to_add, ['invoice'])
```

Not sure how to handle this - I thought I'd solve it by checking if the expense already has an invoice tied to it - if not - include it in the newly created invoice (as seen in `get_billable_expenses()` above) but that means no new expenses will ever be added either as the `invoice`field won't be empty

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: I think you've already solved it with the `Expense.invoice` field. I suspect the true issue is whatever is holding you back from moving forward with that design choice. Can you explain more about the scenario you alluded to in the last paragraph?

Comment: Sure. Seeing as there is a filter in the get_billable_expenses(). How should I proceed? If there is a "invoice=self.id", whenever I create a new expense, no expenses will ever be added because of that filter. And without It, all expenses are always added. Do you see the "paradox"?

Comment: Your lead-in to `get_billable_expenses` say it's on expense, but has a filter for `invoice=self.id`.

Comment: When are you trying to use `get_billable_expenses`? Is that to find un-invoiced expenses or the expenses tied to an invoice? Or both?

Comment: What type of expenses, uninvoiced, invoiced or all?

Comment: So, ideally, when an invoice is created, I want to fetch all expenses that fit a certain criteria. And if I then another invoice, those expenses that were "linked" to invoice #1 should not be linked for invoice #2, does that make sense? Thats the goal

Comment: With `get_billable_expenses` - I'd like to get un-invoiced expenses and add them to the newly created invoice - on this newly created invoice - those expenses fetched from `get_billable_expenses` should be present in my template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by having two methods on my `Invoice` model. One to query for un-invoiced expenses:

```
    def get_billable_expenses(self):
        """Getting all expenses for selected billable period"""
        start_week = self.get_start_isoweek()
        end_week = self.get_end_isoweek()
        return self.project.expense_set.filter(
            expense_date__gte=self.billable_start, 
            expense_date__lte=self.billable_end,
            status='approved',
            billable=True,
            invoice__isnull=True
        )
```

and then in my template showing those expenses as such:

```
    def get_linked_expenses(self):
        return self.project.expense_set.filter(
            invoice=self.id
        )
```